# How to use an IdealCommutingSwitch with BooleanInput

Tags: openmodelica

I've just started using modelica. I have to go build a plant where I have the ability to turn a compressor on or off and then blow air into the compressor or bypass directly into a tank when the switch is in the off position. I thought of using an IdealTwoWaySwitch and an input BooleanInput in order to connect p-n2 when the booelan is 1 (true) and p-n1 when it is false. I don't know how to write the code to connect it all though. I am attaching a photo of the plant in a quantitative way.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNvE3.png)

I tried looking for information on the internet or in books but I couldn't find anything that suited me